# Can't add ":include_blank => "Please select"" to Rails 3.2 option select language(Beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Beginner question
I'm trying to add `{:include_blank => "Please select"}` in line select.

```
%label Please choose the language you speak
.user-profile-select
  %select{id: "user_language_language_id"}
    - Language.active.each do |lang|
      %option{value: lang.id}= lang.to_label
%input{type: "button", value: "ADD", id: "add_user_language"}

%span.note You can choose few

:coffeescript
  $("#add_user_language").click ->
    $.post #{my_user_languages_path.to_json},
      format: 'js'
      user_language:
        language_id: $("#user_language_language_id").val()

    false
```

I'm getting haml error or stay without changes. Who can explain what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: include blank expects true. what you want is `placeholder: "Please Select"`

Comment: I tried to put placeholder in option line option, like that: %option{value: lang.id, placeholder: "Please Select"}= lang.to_label , but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%label Please choose the language you speak
.user-profile-select
  %select{id: "user_language_language_id"}
    %option{class: "prompt"} Please Select
    - Language.active.each do |lang|
      %option{value: lang.id}= lang.to_label
  %input{type: "button", value: "ADD", id: "add_user_language"}

%span.note You can choose few
```

You can provide default "option" tag before the each loop.
You can use form helper methods (select), where you can pass an array and a prompt value.

```
select("lang", "lang_id", Language.active.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:prompt =&gt; 'Please Select'})
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that too in api.rubyonrails.org, and i tried that too. Im getting haml error: "Inconsistent indentation: "  \t" used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces." And I know what that mean. But i put this right and without 2 spaces. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @muzaparofff find a way for your editor to replace tabs with spaces. tabs and spaces are not the same.